# OpenID Connect prompt parameter: SHOULD vs MUST

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, salesforce, openid-connect, okta

The [OpenID Connect Implicit Client specification](http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-implicit-1_0.html) indicates the optional `prompt=login` parameter value for Implicit Clients `SHOULD` prompt the end-user for reauthentication.

Is the right way to interpret `SHOULD` either of the following:

1. `prompt=login` implementations meeting the `SHOULD` requirement should prompt users to reauthenticate when appropriate but may not in certain situations, e.g. prompt the user to reauthenticate where there is no active session, but do not prompt when the user has an active session.
2. `prompt=login` implementations meeting the `SHOULD` requirement `MUST` prompt users to reauthenticate.

If the right way to implement the `SHOULD` requirement is the #2 option above, to always authenticate, how does one handle the situation where the user is only prompted to authenticate if the session has expired? Would this be to omit the `prompt` parameter?

Implementations from Microsoft Azure, Okta, and Salesforce use `MUST` for reauthentication.

References:

- [**OpenID**](http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-implicit-1_0.html): The Authorization Server SHOULD prompt the End-User for reauthentication. If it cannot reauthenticate the End-User, it MUST return an error, typically login_required.
- [**MS Azure**](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-v2-protocols-oauth-code/): `prompt=login` will force the user to enter their credentials on that request, negating single-sign on.
- [**Okta**](http://developer.okta.com/docs/api/resources/oauth2): Can be either none or login. The value determines if Okta should not prompt for authentication (if needed), or force a prompt (even if the user had an existing session). Default: The default behavior is based on whether there’s an existing Okta session.
- [**Salesforce**](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Digging_Deeper_into_OAuth_2.0_on_Force.com): The authorization server must prompt the user for reauthentication, forcing the user to log in again.

Answer (score 1):

For session management, You can use the max_age parameter as defined in the  [openid spec](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html)

Set the max_age to your desired session duration during sign-in to force identity provider to ask for credentials when session expires.